# Proving isomorphism for a Cartesian product modulo function

Tags: analysis

So I have a proofs question:
Prove that if $(m,n) = 1$, then the map $f: \mathbb{Z}_{mn} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{m} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n} $ given by $f:[a]_{mn} \rightarrow ([a]_m, a[n]) $ is an isomorphism.

It was pretty easy to prove that it was homomorphic but I'm pretty frustrated with injectivity and surjectivity. I feel like I don't have enough information to even understand what exactly is going on here. First off, how is this even a function? It seems to me that $mn$ is just the product of $m$ and $n$, yes? But then in that case we can have multiple outputs for the same input. Take for example $mn = 6$. Then we can take $m = 3, n = 2$ or $m = 6, n = 1$ equivalently. And then how can we suppose these congruence classes will be equal for every choice of $a$? Furthermore, shouldn't surjectivity be very straightforward? If $m$ and $n$ exist then surely their product exists. I feel like I'm having a crucial misunderstanding of the domains in question.

Comment: Do you mean if $gcd(m,n)=1$ then $f: \mathbb{Z}_{mn} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ defined by $f([a]_{mn})=([a]_m,[a]_n)$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: You need to specify $m$ and $n$ ahead of time. For example, if you pick $m=6$ and $n=1$ then the result will follow trivially (try to find the map explicitly) and it is not difficult to find the map explicitly for $m=3$ and $n=2$ (brute force should work since you have only 6 elements to play with). For the proof - the Chinese remainder theorem is often the trick in proving surjectivity (look up the statements for rings and look at examples with integers if you haven’t seen it before). Since we have a map between finite rings, injectivity should come automatically following surjectivity.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you saying the function presupposes that you have chosen $m$ and $n$ ahead of time? So in this case $6 =/= 6$ if you came to $6$ using different factors? That would make a lot of sense, but I can't see how I was meant to assume that from the description alone. I feel like that should have been specified. All $mn$ describes is a possible product. Thank you of course for pointing that out I'm just venting my frustration.

Comment: Sorry, mistakenly hit enter. On the CRT - that certainly helps but its proven using very different theorems and ideas available from my own class. I haven't checked out the CRT but I've checked out people tackling this same problem based on logic from the CRT and it didn't help much because they used very different theorems than what I have available.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that this is a group isomorphism?

Comment: I don't know what that means. If it helps I'm trying to prove this is a ring isomorphism.

Comment: A group isomorphism is an isomorphism between groups, whereas a ring isomorphism is an isomorphism between rings. Sometimes two sets can be isomorphic as one algebraic object (such as a group) and not isomorphic as another. You should have studied at the very least elementary group theory before any ring theory.

Comment: Yeah sure seems that way, for whatever reason my class just leaped right into rings directly after real numbers stuff.

Comment: Still really wondering about this, even a pointer in the right direction would be helpful. For surjectivity, why can't I just say that if $m$ and $n$ exist, then their product $mn$ also exists, and that you can use it as the $n$ for a congruence class with $a$? I feel like I don't even need to use the GCD fact at any point during the proof. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_{mn} \to \mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ be defined by $f([a]_{mn})=([a]_m,[a]_n)$. Suppose $\textrm{gcd}(m,n)=1$. We claim that $f$ is a ring isomorphism.

I'll skip proving that $f$ is a ring homomorphism since you already have finished it.

To prove that any homomorphism is injective, the following theorem is very useful: If the kernel of a $f$ is trivial, that is $\textrm{ker}(f)=\{0\}$, then $f$ is injective. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517869/intuition-behind-kernel-is-trivial-implies-homomorphism-is-injective) for more information.

Now, with that theorem, we can show that $f$ is injective. Let $[a]_{mn}
\in \textrm{ker}(f)$, so
$$
([a]_m,[a]_n)=f([a]_{mn})=([0]_m,[0]_n)
$$
Since $[a]_m=[0]_m$, we know $m \mid a$. Similarly, since $[a]_n=[0]_n$, we know $n \mid a$. It follows that since $\textrm{gcd}(m,n)=1$, we have $[a]_{mn}=0$, so $\textrm{ker}(f)=\{0\}$. This finishes the proof that $f$ is injective.

It is not necessary to explicitly show that $f$ is surjective, as the domain and co-domain of $f$ have the same order, and $f$ is injective, so this implies that $f$ must be surjective. [More information on this concept](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826483/cardinality-of-the-domain-vs-codomain-in-surjective-non-injective-injective). $\square$

More importantly, this problem illustrates that knowledge of elementary group theory is very important for understanding the study of rings. A lot of concepts you will encounter for rings will have analogous concepts for groups (ring homomorphism vs group homomorphism, ideal vs normal subgroup), and studying those concepts before undertaking a learning ring theory is fairly important for understanding. I'd suggest you get a [basic abstract algebra textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201763907), and learn some of the basics because they will increase your understanding substantially.

**EDIT**

It's been raised to my attention that you can not use kernel as you have not covered it in class. Because this is for an assignment I am only going to provide hints. The following facts are useful for proving injectivity without using the kernel.

1. If $[a]_n=[b]_n$ then $a \equiv b \ (\textrm{mod} \ n)$.
2. If $a \equiv b \ (\textrm{mod} \ n)$ then $n \mid a-b$.
3. If $a \mid c$, $b \mid c$ and $\textrm{gcd}(a,b)=1$, then $ab \mid c$.

Using these three facts you can prove injectivity in the normal fashion, with around the same ease.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. To show my appreciate I've already accepted it and I will look into the concepts you provided links to for my own understanding. However, I hope you will stick around and help me (although my acceptance of your answer is not contingent on that) with a few other questions, as I cannot use concepts such as kernels because they have not been covered by my class.
I think I have some misunderstandings about what function notation implies in this case. Can we set $[a]_{mn}$ equal to each of $[a]_m$ and $[a]_n$ separately? If so, why? What justifies it?

Comment: Does your class have a textbook or lecture notes? If I got a better idea of what you have learned already I'd be able to provide more help specifically geared towards your class.

Comment: How can I send or upload a pdf for you to view? The prof just sends out the lemmas and theorems to use alongside each assignment. We do follow a book but it isn't required and I don't use it. He also doesn't upload lecture notes.

Comment: Got it, just sent it.

Comment: I added an edit with some hints on how one would prove injectivity without using kernels. Surjectivity follows from injectivity.

Comment: Hey thanks man I appreciate it. If I can ask one more question, why does surjectivity follow from injectivty? Is it because of Lemma 10/10 on the sheet? Then does that mean that the X there does not have to be the same identical set, but just two finite sets?

Comment: If the cardinality of the domain and the codomain of a function are the same, and the function is injective, it must be surjective. Suppose the domain has a cardinality of $n$. Intuitively, since each element in the domain maps to exactly one unique element, the domain maps to a total of $n$ elements. When the codomain has $n$ elements as well, this is enough to guarantee surjectivity. This is necessarily true in the case that the domain and codomain are infinite sets. For example, $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=2x$ is injective, but quite clearly not surjective.

Comment: That makes sense. To clarify - you are saying that the function you mentioned is clearly not surjective in the context you described because the domain and codomain are both infinite and therefore do not have the same cardinality?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100695/discussion-between-dastur-and-bookie).